# Recovering Dogecoin and Bitcoin wallets

Tags: wallet

Back in 2014 I purchased a million Dogecoin and half a Bitcoin. Long story short I dropped my MacBook Pro causing damage to the hard drive. Stupidly I hadn’t backed up the wallets and even more stupidly I opened up the hard drive to look at the platter before shutting it and putting it away.

Anyway we are where we are with crypto today and I think it’s time to try and recover my wallets. I’m under no illusion that this might be impossible but have contacted a data recovery firm who are going to try rebuild and locate the necessary files. Let’s think positively and say they can recover files. My initial question is what files are required? I’m assuming it’d be the wallet.dat files and these would be typically found in:

~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat.
~/Library/Application Support/Dogecoin/wallet.dat
(Unless I’d changed the directory to something else?

Are the wallet.dat files all that are needed or are there other files that I should be looking to locate? Once I have these files I’m confused after reading on here what to do next. There seems to discussion that I could mess things up (a skill of mine) if I am not careful in the recovery at this stage. Would any of you know if there is a guide for recovering wallets either on PC or Mac?

I’m due to send off the hard drive in the near future so will keep you up to date with progress.

Comment: Damaged hard drive = send to a data recovery service, don't try to fix it yourself as you might screw it up more.

Comment: Thanks guys, the drive will be with the data recovery firm today so hoping for the best.